# An R metaprogramming problem: care and feeding of formulae and modeling functions

Tags: r, model, scope, formula, metaprogramming

I want a function that takes a selection of variables, assigns them to new names, produces a formula built from the renamed variables in such a way that a specified modeling formula can use it, and returns the output of the modeling function applied to that formula, data, and any needed additional; arguments. The version below is badly confused about scope, but  I hope it gets the idea across.

```
df  <- tibble(X = 1:3, Y = 4:6, Z = 7:10, T = 11:13, W = 14:16)

quad <- function(dat., A, B, C, D, mod, ...){
   model_data <- select(dat., A = Y, B = X, C = W, D = T) 
   model_data <- mutate(model_data, B2 = B^2, C2 = C^2, D2 = D^2)
   form <- as.formula("A ~ B + C + D + (B + C + D)^2 + B2 + C2 + D2")
   out  <- do.call(mod, args = list(model_data, ...)
   out
}
```

Where the object is that, e.g.,

```
model_quad_lm <- quad(df, A = Y, B = X, C = W, D = T, mod = lm)
```

or

```
model_quad_nlm <- quad(df, A = Y, B = X, C = W, D = T, mod = nlm, p = rep(1, 9))
```

would find Y, X, W, and T in df, assign them to A, B, C & D, respectively, build a formula that is a function of A, B, C & D such as the example of the quadratic expansion shown above, and then evaluate it with the specified modeling function. The ... should allow me to pass other arguments to the modeling function beyond the formula and data. In the end, model_quad_lm should contain the full output of lm in its normal format.

If any of these things, including the modeling function, would be easier by turning a name into a string or a set of names into a list or a character vector, that is fine.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: It's unclear exactly what the question is here. `lm` and `nlm` take very different parameters so I'm not sure what a wrapper around both would look like. It's not super clear what properties you want the returned values to have. What's the desired output that can be used to test possible answers? If you are mostly just conserned with the `eval()` part, then maybe `out  <- eval(as.call(list(substitute(mod), quote(model_data), ...)))` would return something more like what you want?

Comment: I often find I do not really understand my own question until I know the answer, but let's see if this helps. I've edited my question to replace eval with do.call and a list of arguments, starting with the formula and the data. What I am actually doing is evaluating a number of equations in ways that can use the same formula and data throughout, by different assumptions on lag structure or automatic lag order determination method, variable subset selection method, penalization/shrinkage, and the like. Is that any clearer?

Comment: Also, I’m building a small family of these functions, starting with a basic list of the variables, and then estimating various modified versions – the quadratic surface above, the same equation in logs, in difference in logs, maybe some Box-Cox transformations, & etc.  I’m hand-writing the altered equation in each function, although if that works I might make the string I use in as.formula an argument. I’m working on a version that lets me set any one of A, B, C, or D as the LHS variable, looking toward VAR and ARDL implementation, since these equations are generally cointegrated.